# Downloading & Uploading a file with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have been trying to use cURL to interact with an api, I want to download a file with this snippet but all it does is open up the file in the browser and the second snippet is supposed to upload a pdf file along with multipart form data with cURL, but all it give me is;

"{"type":"request_error","detail":"Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"}"

error, I have already tried to execute the thing with postman, it runs fine there and when i copy and paste the same code it still gives me the same errors as above, cheers, thanks in advance.

Here is the code;

Downloading Snippet

```
    $id = "rZFbMKmj2zZbMUbp5KrjCH";

    $auth = $this->access_token;
    $curl = curl_init( PANDA_APIURL . "/documents/".$id."/download");

    //$fp = fopen('Test.pdf', 'w+');
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => PANDA_APIURL . "/documents/".$id."/download",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 50,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      //CURLOPT_FILE => $fp,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Bearer $auth"
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    //fclose($fp);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
```

Uploading the file with multipart form data snippet;

```
    $auth = $this->access_token;
    $boundary = '7aBMjcE3CIYntqQ3';
    $curl = curl_init();

      curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => PANDA_APIURL . "/documents",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '------WebKitFormBoundary7aBMjcE3CIYntqQ3
      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="samplepdf.pdf" 
      Content-Type: application/pdf 


      ------WebKitFormBoundary7aBMjcE3CIYntqQ3
      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

      {  
         "name": "Pdf Doc",    
         "recipients": [  
         {  
             "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
             "first_name": "Jane",
             "last_name": "Roe"   
         }  
        ],
        "fields": {    
            "name": {  
            "value": "John"       
            },
            "like": {  
            "value": true
            }
        }
      }
      ------WebKitFormBoundary7aBMjcE3CIYntqQ3',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Bearer $auth",
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;----WebKitFormBoundary'.$boundary"

      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
```

Comment: Use `CurlFile` as a part of the postfields array to upload a file. You dont need to write raw multipart request, curl will handle it. Unless you want to upload multiple files with the same input name.

Comment: thank you so much!, it worked, can you suggest anything for the first problem, it just opens it up in the browser, it doesn't downloads the file itself

Comment: Use  header to force download. Like `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');`.

Comment: Thank you so much man it worked. And tell me how to mark your comments as an answer.